# Kohana3 pagination module incorrect rendering

Tags: pagination, kohana

I use default kohana 3.2 pagination module.
The search returns about 100 pages of results.
And pagination module renders all 100 links. 
How to fix this?

Comment: here is a screenshot [link](http://gyazo.com/ef95c0e84a2dd47f0584449cd5f892a4)

Comment: there is no "default" pagination module, which one do you use?

Comment: I think this one: https://github.com/kohana/pagination/tree/3.2/develop

Answer (score 0):

Here is your default pagination config:

```
return array(

    // Application defaults
    'default' => array(
        'current_page'      => array('source' => 'query_string', 'key' => 'page'), // source: "query_string" or "route"
        'total_items'       => 0,
        'items_per_page'    => 10,
        'view'              => 'pagination/basic',
        'auto_hide'         => TRUE,
        'first_page_in_url' => FALSE,
    ),

);
```

All you need is switch pagination view from `pagination/basic` to `pagination/floating`. Or you can create and use your own pagination template.